# C# - All objects are getting the same values

Tags: c#

I am coding a chart. This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Val= new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>(); // added
    Val.Clear(); // added
    lineSeries = new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Graph " + i,
        Values = Val,
        Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
        Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
        LineSmoothness = 0,
        PointGeometry = null
    };
    
    for (int jj = 0; jj < 2; jj++)
    {
        Val.Add(new ObservablePoint
        {
            X = jj+i+1,
            Y = jj+i+1
        });
    }
    Col.Add(lineSeries);
}
```

The problem is that in my Col variable (collection) all series are getting the latest values of the loop, which results are lineSeries are the same.
When I use the lineSeries = new LineSeries{}, it should create a new independent object right? Or do I have to erase and create it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `Val`? I can imagine that since the `lineSeries` takes a reference to `Val`, it's updated automatically.

Comment: My mistake.. Sorry!!! Code revised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're reusing the same variable Val to store the actual values. Where is it declared, is it a list? Create a new one each time inside the outer loop and then use it to construct the LineSeries.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var Val = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
    for (int jj = 0; jj < 2; jj++)
    {
        Val.Add(new ObservablePoint
        {
            X = jj+i+1,
            Y = jj+i+1
        });
    }
    var lineSeries = new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Graph " + i,
        Values = Val,
        Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
        Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
        LineSmoothness = 0,
        PointGeometry = null
    };
    
    Col.Add(lineSeries);
}
```

Comment: I've changed my code accordingly to your suggestion. But still the same error.. Thansk!

Comment: @Conor I think you misunderstood is comment because you're still clearing the `Val` every time in your loop therefore the whole code with `Val` seems useless. I don't see any problem with `Col` though

Comment: Too many edits now...

Comment: As Serge points out in a separate answer, you should declare a new lineSeries also within the outer loop, so that you are not overwriting the data every time.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in line series, you use the same variable, and you are adding the same variable. It it changing each time, and in the end have the last data

```
lineSeries = new LineSeries
{
       ......
};
```

should be

```
var lineSeries = new LineSeries
{
       ......
};
```